# Azure Android SDK requirers me to grant access twice before it succeeds..how to fix it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am integrating Azure Active Directory login in Android App. I am using Azure SDK for Android.

When I first sign into AAD and authorize app to use backend service some how authorize page is shown again. When I authorize app this time control comes back to my app. I can see from the log that AuthenticationContext does not find token and start authenticationactivity again.

```
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Remove waiting request: 1102096160 CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f89bf034
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Running task in thread:22384
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Token request started CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f89bf034
W/BrokerProxy(22365): DEVELOPER_BROKER_PERMISSIONS_MISSING:Broker related permissions are missing for GET_ACCOUNTS, MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, USE_CREDENTIALS 
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Checking refresh tokens CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f89bf034
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Looking for regular refresh token CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f89bf034
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Looking for Multi Resource Refresh token CorrelationId: [toke]
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Refresh token is not available CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f89bf034
D/AuthenticationContext(22365): Starting Authentication Activity with callback:1108167280 CorrelationId: 3692c780-c291-4b50-8b45-a464f
```

Is there anything I am missing?